# java.net.MalformedURLException: no protocol: XXX.xml

Tags: java, xml, maven, coding-style

What I wanted to do is:

Force a style check in my build in my Java maven project.

I added this block in my pom.xml:

```
     <build>
        <plugins>
             <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-checkstyle-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.9.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <failOnViolation>true</failOnViolation>
                    <includeTestSourceDirectory>true</includeTestSourceDirectory>
                    <configLocation>${project.basedir}/fishercoder_codestyle.xml</configLocation>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
```

I put `fishercoder_codestyle.xml` file at the same directory where my pom.xml is.

But it simply cannot find it.

What I've tried:

1. I've enabled -X and -e debug mode to get more info, here's the stacktrace:

```
[DEBUG] URLResourceLoader: Exception when looking for '/Users/PATH_TO_MY_PROJECT/fishercoder_codestyle.xml' at ''
java.net.MalformedURLException: no protocol: /Users/PATH_TO_MY_PROJECT/fishercoder_codestyle.xml
    at java.net.URL.(URL.java:593)
    at java.net.URL.(URL.java:490)
    at java.net.URL.(URL.java:439)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.resource.loader.URLResourceLoader.getResource(URLResourceLoader.java:71)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.resource.DefaultResourceManager.getResource(DefaultResourceManager.java:159)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.resource.DefaultResourceManager.getResourceAsFile(DefaultResourceManager.java:91)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.checkstyle.DefaultCheckstyleExecutor.getConfigFile(DefaultCheckstyleExecutor.java:558)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.checkstyle.DefaultCheckstyleExecutor.getConfiguration(DefaultCheckstyleExecutor.java:246)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.checkstyle.DefaultCheckstyleExecutor.executeCheckstyle(DefaultCheckstyleExecutor.java:169)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.checkstyle.CheckstyleViolationCheckMojo.execute(CheckstyleViolationCheckMojo.java:380)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:134)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:207)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:153)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:145)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:116)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:80)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build(SingleThreadedBuilder.java:51)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(LifecycleStarter.java:128)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:307)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:193)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:106)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:863)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:288)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:199)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:289)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:229)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:415)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:356)
```

2. I've given full permission to this .xml file.

Anyone to help please?

EDIT:
Here's my pom.xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.fishercoder</groupId>
    <artifactId>XXX-algorithms</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <build>
        <plugins>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.8</source>
                    <target>1.8</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-checkstyle-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.9.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <failOnViolation>true</failOnViolation>
                    <includeTestSourceDirectory>true</includeTestSourceDirectory>
                    <configLocation>${project.basedir}/fishercoder_codestyle.xml</configLocation>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

        </plugins>
    </build>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.12</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

</project>
```

I don't actually have a settings.xml file in my directory.

Comment: UPDATE:

With @ortomala-lokni help, I put the stylecheck block into `reporting` section, now that error is gone.
However, I don't think this stylecheck is really doing its job:
I have a block below:

    <module name="LineLength">
      <property name="max" value="100"/>
      <property name="ignorePattern" value="^package.*|^import.*|a href|href|http://|https://|ftp://"/>
    </module>

And I've intentionally put multiple lines that are longer than 100 in length, but the stylecheck still succeeded.

Any help please?